# How to figure it out :/ - geolocator_android:compileDebugJavaWithJavac

Tags: flutter, geolocation

I am facing an issue.

I am using "google_maps_place_picker_mb: ^2.0.0-mb.20", which depends on geolocation 8.2.0. Geolocation 9.0.0 is available but geolocation 8.2.0 works with "google_maps_place_picker_mb: ^2.0.0-mb.20.

It worked fine until yesterday. But this suddenly stops working. It seems there is some deprecation in Geolocation.

I have tried all suggestions in StackOverFlow. No luck so far. Do I have to remove "google_maps_place_picker_mb: ^2.0.0-mb.20"? Any suggestions? I started sending my app to testers yesterday... :/

Thanks!

```
/Users/xxxxxx/Developer/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/geolocator_android-3.2.1/android/src/main/java/com/baseflow/geolocator/location/FusedLocationClient.java:199: warning: [deprecation] LocationRequest() in LocationRequest has been deprecated
    LocationRequest locationRequest = new LocationRequest();
                                      ^
/Users/xxxxxx/Developer/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/geolocator_android-3.2.1/android/src/main/java/com/baseflow/geolocator/location/FusedLocationClient.java:222: warning: [deprecation] PRIORITY_NO_POWER in LocationRequest has been deprecated
        return LocationRequest.PRIORITY_NO_POWER;
                              ^
/Users/xxxxxx/Developer/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/geolocator_android-3.2.1/android/src/main/java/com/baseflow/geolocator/location/FusedLocationClient.java:224: warning: [deprecation] PRIORITY_LOW_POWER in LocationRequest has been deprecated
        return LocationRequest.PRIORITY_LOW_POWER;
                              ^
/Users/xxxxxx/Developer/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/geolocator_android-3.2.1/android/src/main/java/com/baseflow/geolocator/location/FusedLocationClient.java:226: warning: [deprecation] PRIORITY_BALANCED_POWER_ACCURACY in LocationRequest has been deprecated
        return LocationRequest.PRIORITY_BALANCED_POWER_ACCURACY;
                              ^
/Users/xxxxxx/Developer/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/geolocator_android-3.2.1/android/src/main/java/com/baseflow/geolocator/location/FusedLocationClient.java:228: warning: [deprecation] PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY in LocationRequest has been deprecated
        return LocationRequest.PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY;
                              ^
error: warnings found and -Werror specified
1 error
5 warnings

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':geolocator_android:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'.


Below are the setting for "app/build.gradle" and "gradle.properties"

<-- app/build.gradle -->

android {

    compileSdkVersion 32

     defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 23
        targetSdkVersion 32
    }

}

<--  gradle.properties  -->

android.useAndroidX=true
android.enableJetifier=true
```

Answer (score 0):

I figured this out.

1. Downgrade the gradle versin in `app/build.gradle` to the previous one.
2. Downgrade the flutter version to the previous one.
3. run `flutter pub cache clean`.
4. run `flutter pub get`.

Comment: for anyone reading today, which version are you referring to?